# Changing URL structure getting DoesNotExist error in Django

Tags: python, django

My current urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('hunt.views',
    url(r'^$', views.top100, name='top100'),
    url(r'^top100/(?P<slug>.+)/$', views.dj, name='dj'),
    url(r'^explore/$', views.explore, name='explore'),
    url(r'^explore/(?P<slug>.+)/$', views.explore_dj, name='explore_dj'),
    url(r'^monthlytop/$', views.monthlytop10, name='monthlytop10'),
    url(r'^trending/$', views.trending, name='trending'),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^thanks/$', views.thanks, name='thanks'),
    url(r'^faq/$', views.faq, name='faq'),
    url(r'^search/(?P<slug>.+)$', views.search, name='search'),
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', direct_to_template,
        {'template': 'sitemap.xml'}),
    url(dajaxice_config.dajaxice_url, include('dajaxice.urls')),
)
```

I want to change my URL from `/top100/slug` and `/explore/slug` to just `/slug`

I did this to my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('hunt.views',
    url(r'^$', views.top100, name='top100'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>.+)/$', views.dj, name='dj'),
    url(r'^explore/$', views.explore, name='explore'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>.+)/$', views.explore_dj, name='explore_dj'),
    url(r'^monthlytop/$', views.monthlytop10, name='monthlytop10'),
    url(r'^trending/$', views.trending, name='trending'),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^thanks/$', views.thanks, name='thanks'),
    url(r'^faq/$', views.faq, name='faq'),
    url(r'^search/(?P<slug>.+)$', views.search, name='search'),
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', direct_to_template,
        {'template': 'sitemap.xml'}),
    url(dajaxice_config.dajaxice_url, include('dajaxice.urls')),
)
```

I am able to access the landing page and all slugs on that page. But if I try to access `explore` or `monthlytop` or any other page I get the `DoesNotExist` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string "explore" matches the regex for the slug, so it will go to that view. You can put all the single-word views before the slug one, so they'll be matched first.

However you are still left with a problem, in that the regexes for dj and explore_dj are exactly the same. You'll need to have some way of differentiating between them.